# Looking for the eigen-function of a system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenfunctions

How could I find the eigen-function of the following system.
Consider the following ODE system
$$\begin{bmatrix}\dot{x}\\\dot{y}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}.$$
The eigen-value is easy to find here,
$$\det(\lambda I - A) = \det\begin{bmatrix}\lambda&-1\\-1&\lambda\end{bmatrix} = \lambda^{2} + 1.$$
Thus we have $\lambda_{1} = i,\lambda_{2} = -i$, and plugging in we got eigen-vector of $A$ are $v_{1} = \begin{bmatrix}-1\\1\end{bmatrix}$, $v_{2} = \begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}$.
But what are the corresponding eigen-function here?

Are they $\exp(tv_{1}), \exp(tv_{2})$ respectively? Or am I missing something?

Ok, made a mistake,
$$\det(\lambda I - A) = \det\begin{bmatrix}\lambda&-1\\-1&\lambda\end{bmatrix} = \lambda^{2} - (-1)^2 = \lambda^{2} - 1 .$$
Thus $\lambda_{1} = 1,\lambda_{2} = -1$, and plugging in we got eigen-vector of $A$ are $v_{1} = \begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}$, $v_{2} = \begin{bmatrix}-1\\1\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Hint: differentiate both sides again, and you'll get 2 ODEs.

Comment: Ok, made a mistake,
$$\det(\lambda I - A) = \det\begin{bmatrix}\lambda&-1\\-1&\lambda\end{bmatrix} = \lambda^{2} - (-1)^2 = \lambda^{2} - 1 .$$
Thus $\lambda_{1} = 1,\lambda_{2} = -1$, and plugging in to have eigen-vector of $A$ as $v_{1} = \begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}$, $v_{2} = \begin{bmatrix}-1\\1\end{bmatrix}$.
Therefore the eigen-function are $\exp(t)\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}$ and $\exp(-t)\begin{bmatrix}-1\\1\end{bmatrix}$.
Am I correct here now?